# Excel macro copy function

Tags: vba, excel

I know this question has already been asked but I would like to understand what I'm doing wrong

I just want to copy a cell to another cell in a different worksheet. The copied cell depend on the row where is located the button.

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateButtons()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim shp As Object
    Dim dblLeft As Double
    Dim dblTop As Double
    Dim dblWidth As Double
    Dim dblHeight As Double

    With Sheets("SALES UNFULFILLED")
        dblLeft = .Columns("AZ:AZ").Left      'All buttons have same Left position
        dblWidth = .Columns("AZ:AZ").Width    'All buttons have same Width
        For i = 2 To 200                     'Starts on row 2 and finishes row 20
            dblHeight = .Rows(i).Height     'Set Height to height of row
            dblTop = .Rows(i).Top           'Set Top top of row
            Set shp = .Buttons.Add(dblLeft, dblTop, dblWidth, dblHeight)
            shp.OnAction = "IdentifySelected"
            shp.Characters.Text = "Invoice"
        Next i
    End With  
End Sub


Sub IdentifySelected()
    'NOTE: The button will always be on the active sheet
    Dim strButtonName
    Dim lngRow As Long

    strButtonName = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name
    lngRow = ActiveSheet.Shapes(strButtonName).TopLeftCell.Row
    'MsgBox "Button is on row " & lngRow
    Worksheets("invoice").Range(Cells(5, 3)).Value = Worksheets("SALES UNFULFILLED").Range(Cells(lngRow, 4)).Value
End Sub
```

I keep getting an error 1004  on this line of code but I don't understand why
`Worksheets("invoice").Range(Cells(5, 3)).Value = Worksheets("SALES UNFULFILLED").Range(Cells(lngRow, 4)).Value`

I tried to change "Value" by "Select" but no chance

Comment: Try `Worksheets("invoice").Range(Worksheets("invoice").Cells(5, 3)).Value = Worksheets("SALES UNFULFILLED").Range(Worksheets("invoice").Cells(lngRow, 4)).Value` or just `Worksheets("invoice").Cells(5, 3).Value = Worksheets("SALES UNFULFILLED").Cells(lngRow, 4).Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to change:

```
Worksheets("invoice").Range(Cells(5, 3)).Value = Worksheets("SALES UNFULFILLED").Range(Cells(lngRow, 4)).Value
```

to

```
Worksheets("invoice").Cells(5, 3).Value = Worksheets("SALES UNFULFILLED").Cells(lngRow, 4).Value
```

Hope this help